# Implementing where condition in DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a scenario wherein I want to implement a BELOW SQL Query in Dax:

```
select count(distinct a.ID)
from Table1 a
join Table2 b
  on a.ID=b.ID
where a.[In_Time] = "No" OR b.[In Time] = "No"
```

how do I implement using Dax?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those redundant parentheses to avoid confusion - i.e. simply do `COUNT(DISTINCT a.ID)`.

Comment: @jarlh I see you put this comment at least once a day lol

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide much of details as to what is is the relationship between t1 and t2 and whether you expect this through a DAX `query` or DAX `measure`.

Assuming you want this to be returned through `DAX query` with no relationship between `t1` and `t2` an equivalent `DAX` query  would be following. It joins a filtered `t1` and filtered `t2` on desired criteria.

`t1`

```
| id | inTime |
|----|--------|
| 1  | yes    |
| 1  | no     |
| 2  | no     |
| 3  | no     |
| 4  | no     |
| 5  | no     |
| 6  | no     |
```

`t2`

```
| id | inTime |
|----|--------|
| 1  | yes    |
| 1  | no     |
| 2  | yes    |
| 3  | no     |
| 5  | no     |
```

`Query`

```
Table =
VAR _1 =
    DISTINCT (
        NATURALINNERJOIN (
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                FILTER ( t1, t1[inTime] = "no" ),
                "id", t1[id] + 0,
                "inTIme", t1[inTime] & ""
            ),
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                FILTER ( t2, t2[inTim] = "no" ),
                "id", t2[id] + 0,
                "inTIme", t2[inTim] & ""
            )
        )
    )
VAR _2 =
    ROW ( "count", COUNTX ( _1, [id] ) )
RETURN
    _2
```

`returns` the following for `VAR _1`

```
| id | inTime |
|----|--------|
| 1  | no     |
| 3  | no     |
| 5  | no     |
```

Comment: sorry for less information there ,i wanted to implement this in DAX measure

Comment: Improve your question